# Access the top window panel buttons in tkinter Python 3? (Maximize, Minimize, Close)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, window

I want to be able to call the top window panel buttons in tkinter Python 3. 
For example, i want to make the maximize button perform the maximize option along with some more functions explicitly. Something like, assume we have the name of the maximize button is 'Max'

```
if (Max, 'pressed'):
 Initializecanvas1()
else:
 Initializecanvas2()
```

I saw something about this WM DELETE WINDOW

```
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', <function>)
```

Similarly is there anything for the other two buttons such as Maximize and Minimize? Also is it possible to be able to perform some functions using it such as the one i mentioned above?